# How to disable mouse clicks and mouse drags on a NSView?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, swift5

I am making a mac app using Swift and this app has a custom view (a class extending NSView and overriding its draw method). Now, I want to disable all mouse clicks and mouse drags on this view and pass them on to the other applications running beneath my application.

I have tried the following ways (gleaned from Apple documentation and other SO questions) to disable clicks on my view and nothing worked for me so far:

**1. Overriding hitTest inside my custom View class**

```
override func hitTest(_ point: NSPoint) -> NSView? {
    let view = super.hitTest(point)
    return view == self ? nil : view
}
```

**2. Overriding acceptsFirstMouse inside my custom View class**

```
override func acceptsFirstMouse(for event: NSEvent?) -> Bool {
    return false
}
```

**3. Overriding mouseDown in ViewController as well as in my custom View class**

```
override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {
    // do nothing
}
```

**4. Overriding mouseDragged in ViewController as well as in my custom View class**

```
override func mouseDragged(with event: NSEvent) {
    // do nothing
}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Is this view (and superview, etc) has transparent (alpha 1.0) areas?

Comment: I guess Transparent => alpha 0.0. No, the view doesn't have transparent areas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't handled at the view level, it's handled at the window level. You can set the `ignoresMouseEvents` property of the window to true.

The issue is that the Window Server will only dispatch an event to a single process. So, once it has arrived in your app, it's not going to another. And there's no feasible way for your app to forward it along, either.

Comment: This worked, great! Also, the events act on other applications beneath my app as my window background is set to `.clear` (even though my custom view is opaque). This is exactly what I wanted.